# Firefox not able to find iframe

Tags: javascript, html

This is the iframe I'm trying to access:

```
 <div class="mceBody" id="additionalTxt_b">
        <iframe frameborder="0" id="additionalTxt_f" src='javascript:""' class="punymce"/>
 </div>
```

Using this line:

```
frames['additionalTxt_f'].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML
```

For some reason I'm getting "frames.additionalTxt_f is undefined" from firebug.
I have similar iframes (dynamically created by punyMCE plugin) on other pages, and they work perfectly fine. And IE7/8 has no problem accessing this iframe either.

Just at a complete loss here. Any ideas on why Firefox can't find the iframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `window.frames[]` array is indexed by the [i]frame's `name` attribute (aka frame target). `id` can't be relied upon to also work — although it may in IE <8, which often thinks names and ids are the same thing.

If you want to access a frame's content via ID, use the DOM Level 2 HTML `contentDocument` property instead of the old-school (“DOM Level 0”) `frames` array:

```
document.getElementById('additionalTxt_f').contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

...but then, for compatibility with IE <8, you also have to add some fallback cruft, since it doesn't support `contentDocument`:

```
var f= document.getElementById('additionalTxt_f');
var d= f.contentDocument? f.contentDocument : f.contentWindow.document;
d.body.innerHTML
```

So it's up to you which method you think is less ugly: the extra script work, or just using the `name` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. And with this I found yet another bug with pumyMCE, since it didn't add the name attribute to the iframe.

Comment: Well... ‘bug’ might be overselling it, there's no particular requirement to include a `name` attribute. Some people prefer `name`, some `id` (and it's conceivable you might not want either).

Comment: oh. just a little heads up. In the if-sentence it's supposed to be f.contentWindow, not d.contentWindow...just found the type-o now, as it produced an error in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

if you have only 1 iframe you can also find it with window.frames[1] or
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]

(In the first option, the parent window is #0)