# how do i pass a URL address from a parent to iframe when clicking on something in the parent?

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent-child

I have an html page with an iframe in it. The iframe only does 1 thing which holds the longtail video player. Here is the code for the longtail video player (the iframe)...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','725','415','9');
  so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
  so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
  so.addParam('wmode','opaque');
  so.addVariable('file','VIDEOFILENAME.FLV');
  so.addVariable('displayclick','fullscreen');
  so.addVariable('icons','false');
  so.write('mediaspace');
</script>
```

What i'm looking to do is pass a file name from the parent (the file is on my server) to the above code and replace "videofilename.flv" and then play that file. This sending of the file name should occur when an image is clicked. How do I do this? Basically I'll have 20 images which when clicked will each individually play a different video in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720870/firefox-not-able-to-find-iframe/720886#720886) helps?  The iframes on a page are accessible via an array.