# set div's innerHTML with an iframe, shows up in firebug but not on page

Tags: iframe, extjs4, innerhtml

I'm using the extjs library. I've got a blank panel and I want to load another one of my ext projects into it with an iframe. Here is my function (called from a button), "thepanel" is my blank panel.

```
function(button){
    var div = document.getElementById('thepanel');
    div.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"../../../project2/?&type=grades&gradeitem1=40691&\"></iframe>";
}
```

I can see the GET request in firebug's console when I run the function and all my second project code/data all shows up in an iframe when I look a the HTML in firebug but nothing new shows up in the browser. Any ideas of what could be keeping my iframe's contents from showing

I am using MVC architecture, here is the code that declares my panel:

```
items:[{
        xtype:'panel',
        itemId:'two',
        id:'thepanel',
        region:'center',
}]
```

**UPDATE**: I've tried moving the iframe to the html config option of the panel instead of adding it through jquery with a button click. Again, I can see the code from the url in the iframe show up in firebug but nothing shows up in my application. Here is the code declaring my panel:

```
xtype:'panel',
itemId:'two',
id:'thepanel',
region:'center',
html:'<iframe src=\"../../../extjproh2/?&type=grades&gradeitem1=40691\"></iframe>',
height:400,
width:400,
```

Comment: check following post 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896458/documentelement-innerhtml-not-showing-the-iframe-body 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720870/firefox-not-able-to-find-iframe/720886#720886

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how extjs works.  Please provide the code where you create the panel and I can show you a method that will work.

Comment: RDSAGAR: I'm looking into those posts
Reimius: I posted my code where I create the panel above, its pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this plugin from the sencha forums:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?110311-iframePanel&p=943573#post943573